# how to share data between different camel contexts

Tags: apache-camel

Is there a way to share data through different contexts.
I have created a custom component which i want to initialise only once.while initialising iam setting some properties which iam not able to access in another context.

How to access those?

Thanks.

Regards
Senthil Kumar Sekar

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `VM` component. This component provides an asynchronous way of sending messages across camel contexts with a `SEDA`-fashion. For more info, please refer to the actual [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/vm.html).

Also, I am not sure how you are setting those values but you could use two routes within the same context probably. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yep, `vm` is designed for that. Otherwise you can use queues, hazelcast, or whatever.